# The UI brokes up after knockoutjs re-binds the viewmodel

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

As it's written in title: When I add an object to a property of type  ko.observableArray,  knockoutjs updates the view, which is fine for me.

The problem is the view margins itself about 100px from left side after view update. And suprisingly when I select the whole view by mouse-leftclick the view fixes and left margin affect disappears. By the way this happens in IE 8.

Also I tried this in Chrome the same thing happens: somehow left-margin is applied to the view; On the contrary, this time selecting the view doesn't fix the problem as I described in previous pharagraph.

This may be about jquery too but I'm truly not sure.

You may see the view and viewmodel below (It's kind of complicated.) I also put the screenshots (on IE8) that related with the problem.

Before I hit the Enter key: "http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/6598/minqbeforeenter.png"

After hit the Enter key: "http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/1905/minqafterenter.png"

After I select with mouse-leftclick: "http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/882/minqafterselect.png"

the script I'm using (When I hit Enter key on the textbox AdvancedSearchControlViewModel's searchValue_keydown method is working)

```
function SearchControlViewModel(context) {
    var normalizeSelectItems = function (selectItems) {
        var normalizedItems = [];

        if (!(selectItems && $.isArray(selectItems) && selectItems.length > 0))
            return normalizedItems;

        for (var index = 0; index < selectItems.length; index++) {
            var item = selectItems[index];
            if (item.Items && $.isArray(item.Items)) {
                if (item.Items.length <= 0)
                    continue;
                var group = { Value: item.Value, Description: item.Description };
                for (var index2 = 0; index2 < item.Items.length; index2++) {
                    var subItem = item.Items[index2];
                    normalizedItems.push(new SelectItem({ Value: subItem.Value, Description: subItem.Description, Group: group }));
                }
            } else {
                normalizedItems.push(new SelectItem({ Value: item.Value, Description: item.Description, Group: { Description: ''} }));
            }
        }

        return normalizedItems;
    };
    var normalizedSelectItems = normalizeSelectItems(context.SelectItems);
    context.SelectedValues = normalizeSelectItems(context.SelectedValues);
    $.each(context.SelectedValues, function (selectedIndex, selectedItem) {
        var selItem;
        $.each(normalizedSelectItems, function (selectIndex, selectItem) {
            if (selectItem.Value === selectedItem.Value) {
                selItem = selectItem;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (selItem) {
            context.SelectedValues[selectedIndex] = selItem;
        }
    });

    var self = this;

    self.allOptions = 'All';

    self.selectItems = ko.observableArray(normalizedSelectItems);

    self.searchContext = new SearchContext(context);

    self.DropDownCheckList = function (elements) {

        $('select', elements).dropdownchecklist({
            firstItemChecksAll: true,
            forceMultiple: true,
            onItemClick: function (checkBox, originalSelect) {
                var selectedItem;
                for (var selectedItemIndex = 0; selectedItemIndex < originalSelect.options.length; selectedItemIndex++) {
                    if (originalSelect.options[selectedItemIndex].value === checkBox.val()) {
                        selectedItem = originalSelect.options[selectedItemIndex];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                selectedItem.selected = checkBox.attr('checked') === 'checked';
            },
            maxDropHeight: 300,
            width: 250,
            emptyText: 'Please Select...'
            /*,
            textFormatFunction: function (options) {
            return 'Filtre';
            }*/
        });
    };

    self.Validate = function () {
        var check;

        check = self.searchContext.searchValue();
        if (check === null || check === undefined ||
            check === '')
            return false;

        check = self.searchContext.selectedItems();
        if (check === null || check === undefined ||
            !$.isArray(check) || check.length === 0)
            return false;

        var hasAtLeastOneItem = false;
        $.each(check, function (index) {
            if (check[index]) {
                hasAtLeastOneItem = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        return hasAtLeastOneItem;
    };

    self.GetConvertedJSONObj = function () {
        var obj = {
            SelectedValues: [],
            SearchValue: self.searchContext.searchValue()
        };

        var selectedItems = self.searchContext.selectedItems();
        if (selectedItems) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
                var selItem = selectedItems[i];
                if (selItem === null || selItem === undefined)
                    continue;

                var pushArray;
                if (selItem.Group.Description !== '') {
                    var group = undefined;
                    $.each(obj.SelectedValues, function (index, item) {
                        if (item.Items && $.isArray(item.Items)) {
                            if (item.Value === selItem.Group.Value) {
                                group = item;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (group === undefined) {
                        pushArray = [];
                        obj.SelectedValues.push({
                            Value: selItem.Group.Value,
                            Items: pushArray
                        });
                    } else {
                        pushArray = group.Items;
                    }

                } else {
                    pushArray = obj.SelectedValues;
                }

                pushArray.push({
                    Value: selItem.Value
                });
            }
        }

        return obj;
    };
    self.ConvertToJSON = function () {
        var obj = self.GetConvertedJSONObj();

        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    };
}
function SearchContext(context) {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(context.SelectedValues);

    self.searchValue = ko.observable(context.SearchValue);
}
function SelectItem(context) {
    var self = this;

    self.Value = context.Value;
    self.Text = context.Description;
    self.Group = context.Group;
}

function SearchFilter(context) {
    var self = this;

    var getSelectedItemsDescription = function (selectedItems) {
        var text = '';
        var selectedValues = context.template.searchContext.selectedItems();
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
            var selectedValue = selectedValues[i];

            text += selectedValue.Text;
            if (i + 1 < selectedValues.length)
                text += ', ';
        }

        return text;
    };
    self.selectedValuesDescription = getSelectedItemsDescription(
        context.template.searchContext.selectedItems()
    );

    self.searchValueText = context.template.searchContext.searchValue();

    self.filterCombineType = context.defaultCombineType.key;

    self.GetConvertedJSONObj = function () {
        var obj = context.template.GetConvertedJSONObj();
        obj.CombineType = self.filterCombineType;

        return obj;
    };
    self.ConvertToJSON = function () {
        var obj = self.GetConvertedJSONObj();

        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    };
}
function AdvancedSearchControlViewModel(context) {
    var self = this;

    self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate = ko.observable(new SearchControlViewModel(context.data.TemplateSearch));

    // key , value
    self.SearchFilterCombineTypes = [];
    for (var ct in context.data.SearchCombineTypes) {
        self.SearchFilterCombineTypes.push({ key: ct, value: context.data.SearchCombineTypes[ct] });
    }

    self.searchFilters = [];
    if ($.isArray(context.data.Searchs) && context.data.Searchs.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < context.data.Searchs.length; i++) {
            var search = context.data.Searchs[i];
            var searchFilter;
            $.each(self.SearchFilterCombineTypes, function (index, element) {
                if (element.key === search.CombineType.toString()) {
                    searchFilter = element;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            search.SelectItems = context.data.TemplateSearch.SelectItems;

            self.searchFilters.push(
                new SearchFilter({ template: new SearchControlViewModel(search), defaultCombineType: searchFilter })
            );
        }
    }
    self.searchFilters = ko.observableArray(self.searchFilters);

    self.addSearchFilter = function () {
        if (self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate().Validate()) {
            self.searchFilters.push(new SearchFilter({ template: self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate(), defaultCombineType: self.SearchFilterCombineTypes[0] }));
            self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate(new SearchControlViewModel(context.data.TemplateSearch));
        }
    };

    self.searchValue_keydown = function (sender, event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            // Code block to prevent submit
            /*var fnDontSubmit = function () {
            $(this).unbind('submit', fnDontSubmit);
            return false;
            };
            $(event.currentTarget.form).bind('submit', fnDontSubmit);*/

            self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate().searchContext.searchValue(event.srcElement.value);
            self.addSearchFilter();
        }
        return true;
    };

    self.iButton = function (elements, bindings) {
        var boundSearchFilter = bindings;

        var elem = $(elements).filter('[type="checkbox"]');

        if (boundSearchFilter.filterCombineType === self.SearchFilterCombineTypes[1].key)
            elem.attr('checked', 'checked');
        else
            elem.removeAttr('checked');

        elem.iButton({
            labelOn: self.SearchFilterCombineTypes[1].value,
            labelOff: self.SearchFilterCombineTypes[0].value,
            change: function (sender, event) {
                var selectedVal = self.SearchFilterCombineTypes[sender.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0];
                boundSearchFilter.filterCombineType = selectedVal.key;
                // if you remove this line and 
                // make filterCombineType an observable 
                // the iButton animation wont work. So We're binding the checkbox manually.
                ko.applyBindings(self, $('#' + context.valueId)[0]);
            }
        });

        var isLastElem = $(self.searchFilters()).last()[0] === boundSearchFilter;
        if (isLastElem)
            elem.iButton('disable');
    };

    self.ConvertToJSON = function () {
        var jsonFilterArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < self.searchFilters().length; i++) {
            var searchFilter = self.searchFilters()[i];
            jsonFilterArr.push(searchFilter.GetConvertedJSONObj());
        }

        return JSON.stringify({
            Searchs: jsonFilterArr
        });
    };
}

if (!$.data(document, "BindKnockoutjsControl")) {
    $.data(document, "BindKnockoutjsControl", function (context) {
        switch (context.controlType) {
            case 'SearchControl':

                var viewModel = new SearchControlViewModel(context.dataForViewModel);

                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + context.controlDisplayIdToBind)[0]);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + context.controlValueIdToBind)[0]);

                break;
            case "AdvancedSearchControl":

                var viewModel = new AdvancedSearchControlViewModel({ data: context.dataForViewModel, valueId: context.controlValueIdToBind });

                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + context.controlDisplayIdToBind)[0]);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#' + context.controlValueIdToBind)[0]);

                break;
            default:
                throw 'Unknown controlType: ' + context.controlType;
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

The view

```
<script id="AdvancedSearchControl_View" type="text/html">
    <table style="display:inline-block; width: 25%;">
        <thead data-bind="template: { name: 'SearchControl_View' }">
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'AdvancedSearchControlItem_View', foreach: $data.searchFilters }">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
<script id="SearchControl_View" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvancedSearchViewModel, new { @class = "SearchControlCaption" })
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:9px;">
            <select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: SearchControlViewModelTemplate().selectItems, selectedOptions: SearchControlViewModelTemplate().searchContext.selectedItems, optionsText: 'Text', optionsGroup: function(item){return item.Group !== '' ? item.Group.Description : ''}, optionsCaption: SearchControlViewModelTemplate().allOptions"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="SearchValue" data-bind="
                    value: SearchControlViewModelTemplate().searchContext.searchValue,
                    event: {
                        keydown: searchValue_keydown
                    }
                "
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + Models.ResourceFiles.Resources._SearchButtonFileName)" 
                data-bind="enable: $data.searchFilters().length > 0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="AdvancedSearchControlItem_View" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.selectedValuesDescription"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.searchValueText"></td>
        <td />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="template: { name: 'AdvancedSearchControlItemRadios_View', afterRender: $root.iButton }">
        </td>
        <td />
        <td />
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="AdvancedSearchControlItemRadios_View" type="text/html">
    <input type="checkbox" name="AndOr" />
</script>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you produce a more condensed demonstration of the problem in jsfiddle? Fork this example to get started. http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/bNSSq/

Comment: [There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/rebulanyum/VKdxZ/). But I don't see the error there.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the searchValue_keydown function as below;

```
self.searchValue_keydown = function (sender, event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
            self.SearchControlViewModelTemplate().searchContext.searchValue(event.currentTarget.value);
            self.addSearchFilter();
            /* ADDED the code below to fix the issue; While knockoutjs updates */
            /* the ui but not forcing to apply css styles; thought I can update */
            /* the ui again by inserting into DOM again with dummy empty text. */
            /* And I succeded. */
            $('#' + context.displayId).append(' ');
        }
        return true;
    };
```